# Facing issue with TfvcTempalte.12.xaml for Cloaked functionality in TFS 2013 build configuration

Tags: tfs

![enter image description here][1]

we are configuring source settings like above image![enter image description here][2].

$/Product-X/Dev/Source/ProductX_UI/kendoUI.sln - 3 error(s), 0 warning(s), View Log File
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (182): Could not copy the file "Modules\TDC\AliasConfig\AliasConfig.html" because it was not found.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (182): Could not copy the file "Modules\TDC\AliasConfig\AliasConfigTemplate.js" because it was not found.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (182): Could not copy the file "Modules\TDC\AliasConfig\AliasConfigVM.js" because it was not found.
 $/Product-X/Dev/Source/ProductX_UI/kendoUI.sln compiled
 No Test Results
 No Code Coverage Results
Other Errors and Warnings
 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
 Exception Message: MSBuild error 1 has ended this build. You can find more specific information about the cause of this error in above messages. (type BuildProcessTerminateException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

giving above error. please provide any solution for this.

Comment: my source settings are below:

Comment: $/Product-X/Dev/Source/ProductX_UI: $(SourceDir)
 (cloaked) $/Product-X/Dev/Source/ProductX_UI/kendoUI/Modules/TDC: